# What's the old version of matmul() in Numpy for matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix, numpy-einsum

I need to use an older version of NumPy which doesn't have matmul() in it. What's the original way to multiply matrices in NumPy? I know * is elementwise multiplication and that .dot() is different in certain cases. I just want the standard linear algebra multiplication.

Thanks.

Comment: What is "the standard linear algebra multiplication"? If you mean [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), then it is `np.matmul` (equivalent to `@` operator in modern Python) or `np.dot`. If you mean element-wise multiplication, it is `np.multiply` or `*` operator. Are neither of these what you want?

Comment: For 2d arrays, `dot` is the same thing.

Comment: `dot`  and `matmul` differ in how they extend 'standard matrix product' to 3d (and larger) arrays.  Think of it as batch processing of 2d arrays.  `np.einsum` has been around for some time too, and gives even more flexibility in handling higher dimensions.

Comment: @hpaulj so I can multiply any matrices (2D obviously) together with dot() and it's the same thing?